# BufferedWriter - unknown source exception

Tags: java, exception, bufferedwriter

I am making some java libraries called cake util and one of the things that is in there is a WriteFile class with a write() method.
Now when I try to call the method an **unknown source** exception occurs

This is my code:

```
package Cake_Util.file;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import Cake_Util.console.Info;
import Cake_Util.console.Security;

public class WriteFile {

    private File f;

    public WriteFile(File path){
        if(path.exists()){
            this.f = path;
        }else{
            Info i = new Info("warn");
            i.print("Warning! the file doesnt exist");
            Security s = new Security();
            s.stop();
        }
    }

    public void write(String text){

        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        try {
            bw.write(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            fw.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void newLine(){
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        try {
            bw.newLine();
            fw.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}
```

P.S. sorry the indentation is a bit rubbish when I tried to put it in here, my fault :(

The exception is:

```
[18:31:34 Info] Creating file...
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(Unknown Source)
at Cake_Util.file.WriteFile.write(WriteFile.java:42)
at mainPackage.lol.main.ThisIsATest.main(ThisIsATest.java:18)
```

Comment: paste full stacktrace

Comment: Don't eat your exceptions by catching them and calling `e.printStackTrace()` otherwise you will face weird bugs like this one as it doesn't prevent the program to continue

Comment: @GautamSavaliya here it is: [18:31:34 Info] Creating file...
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(Unknown Source)
 at Cake_Util.file.WriteFile.write(WriteFile.java:42)
 at mainPackage.lol.main.ThisIsATest.main(ThisIsATest.java:18)

Comment: @NathanProgrammer add to question.

Comment: I added to question. @GautamSavaliya

Comment: @NicolasFilotto and how do i avoid eating them up then?

Comment: let the method throws the excetion

Comment: @NathanProgrammer Well, what should your method do if the file cannot be written? Fail with exception the caller *must* handle. Fail with exception that caller generally wouldn't handle, allowing it to cascade up the call stack? Silently ignore the error, so nothing it written but nobody knows?

Comment: don't you have to close fw before bw? (since bw was opened after fw)

Comment: @Leo You only have to close `bw`. It will close `fw` for you. Even better, use try-with-resource so you don't have to close either. Also has better error handling if close fails.

Comment: Don't rename SO questions to "SOLVED ....". Either delete the question if you no longer want it answered, or accept an answer. If you've found the answer independently, you can write it yourself then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer:
I had to close only bw and it would then automatically close fw. That is what the exception was